# What are equivalent open source libraries to these closed source ones?

Tags: .net, open-source, components, libraries

I have a project (.NET 3.0, c#) that needs to be converted to open source (probably GPLv2).

The project uses some closed source libraries at its core that need to be replaced with open source ones.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the best open source replacements for the following libraries?

- [Infragistics (Windows Forms)](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx#Overview) (primarily treeview, listview, chart, reporting engine (xps,pdf))
- [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/)
- [IPWorks](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/) (primarily http client, tcp client, smtp client, pop3 client)
- [IPWorks SSL](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssl/) (primarily https client, smtps client, pop3s client)
- [IPWorks SNMP](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssnmp/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

VistaDB can be replaced by [MySQL](http://mysql.com), [SQLite](http://sqlite.org), or even the express version of [SQL Server 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) (although SQL Server is not GPL).

Comment: Indeed, for an open source project you would normally try to allow any reasonably modern database backend, rather than tie to a single embedded engine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple [SMTP client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) built into .Net.